# Windows 11: xgboost Module Not Found

Tags: python, xgboost

I am getting an error when I import `xgboost`

```
import xgboost as xgb


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/harsh/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xgboost as xgb
  File "G:\My Drive\Oddsportal\venv\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Booster
  File "G:\My Drive\Oddsportal\venv\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "G:\My Drive\Oddsportal\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "G:\My Drive\Oddsportal\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I checked, it is installed.

[Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zobYO.jpg)

It was working fine and I installed/upgraded to Windows 11 and this is a new error for me.

Comment: I think xgboost still lacks Windows 11 support.

Comment: Oh man. This is a crucial bit of my workflow and I did not check this bit before I moved over to 11. I feel I should had checked it. My bad